# HtmlCollection instead of Array from Xml tag

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have some xml in which I want to remove some set of tags as per condition. My xml looks like

XML :

```
<A>
    <A1 
    <R Val= "A" Flg = 0 </R>
    <R Val= "A" Flg = 1 </R>
    </A1>
</A>

<B>
    <B1> 
    <R Val= "B" Flg = 0</R>
    <R Val= "B" Flg = 1</R>
    </B1>
</B>
```

Now I want remove R tag which having Flg having 0. so for that my idea get the attribute then check the condition and then remove from Xml.

so here I am trying is

```
var xm = XML.getaAttributeBytag("R");
```

here in xm i am getting like array of R tag. but when i am trying to use remove at index method i am getting this as **HTMlCollection** not array.

What is this difference and how to remove R tag.

Comment: Your `R` tag does not have attribute `Flg` nor `Val`. It's only text node that has text as `Val= "B" Flg = 0`. Can you provide more clear example in Snippet?

Comment: i edited my xml. please check